# Laravel Nova - Point Nova path to resource page

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to point Nova path to a resouce. So that when a user login, he`ll directed to that particular resource.

I have updated this path in `/config/nova.php`:

```
'path' => '/crm/resources/clients'
```

Now after login, I can see the URL updated. But the page is still Welcome Nova page.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom [Asset](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/assets.html) or [Tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html) to hook into the Vue Router.  In our specific case, we wanted to redirect to our custom tool instead of a resource or the dashboard.  Creating a tool generates a `tool.js` file where it allows you to hook into the vue-router.

---

#### Redirect from the dashboard to a *named route*

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if (to.name == "dashboard.custom") {
      next({
          name: "reports" // Route added by our tool
      });
   } else {
      next();
   }
});
```

#### Redirect from the dashboard to a *resource index*

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if (to.name == "dashboard.custom") {
      next({
          name: "index",
          params: {
            resourceName: 'model' // replace with resource name
          }
      });
   } else {
      next();
   }
});
```

Note `resourceName` is the name of the dynamic segment defined in the index route.

[image: Showing why resourceName is used as the property name in the code above]