# Laravel nova - redirect from Dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to remove dashboard from my [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) app.

I found it easy to remove it from sidebar-menu - simply comment `/views/dashboard/navigation.blade.php` code.

However, I want to add a redirection logic (landing page depends on user role) so when navigating to `/` user will be redirected to a resource or tool which corresponds him.

(I have already implemented a redirection after login (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345123/1039488)

I tried to do it with cards, but looks like this is not the right solution.

Any idea where can I place the redirection logic?

Comment: Do you have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 9):

Nova 4; You can override the `initialPath` like so:

```php
class NovaServiceProvider extends NovaApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Nova::initialPath('/resources/users');
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you get redirected to the `Users` resource upon logging in.

Comment: Thnks! Best answer!

Comment: Note that initialPath accepts a closure if you want to redirect per-role ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pre nova 4 method:

To NovaServiceProvider.php add to boot method:

```
Nova::script('menuFix', __DIR__.'/../../resources/js/fixMenu.js');
```

Create file fixMenu.js with following:

```
if (location.pathname == '/' || location.pathname == '/dashboards/main'){
    location.href = '/whereToRedirect'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner and safe way for `Nova 3.x or below`:

- Copy `vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php` to `resources/views/vendor/nova/`
- Now open `resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php` and edit it
- Replace this line with the code below `window.Nova = new CreateNova(config);`

```
    window.Nova = new CreateNova(config);
    window.Nova.booting((Vue, router, store) => {
        /** This fixes showing an empty dashboard. */
        router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            if (to.name === 'dashboard.custom') {
                next({ name: 'index', params: { resourceName: 'users'}});
            }

            next();
        });
    });
```

- Replace `users` with your entity name's plural like `products`
- Now save the file and refresh the nova `dashboard` and you should see the new page.

The solution was taken from [here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/393#issuecomment-779874415) with clear steps.

The solution may also work for `4.x`, but I haven't checked it yet.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out myself. In your Routes/web.php file, add a redirect route:

```
Route::redirect('/','/resources/{resource_name}');
```

where {resource_name} is the plural form of the resource. For example, '/resources/posts'.

In your case, you may want to redirect to your own control file, where the redirect logic can be placed.

```
Route::get('/', 'YourController@rootRedirectLogic');
```

Then in the controller YourController, add the method:

```
public function rootRedirectLogic(Request $request) {
    // some logic here
    return redirect()->route('YourRoute');
}
```

where 'YourRoute' is the name of the route you want to send the user to.

(Found clues to this solution in a comment by dillingham here: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/393)

Comment: It doesn't work. Something it's overwriting the redirect in 'routes'

Comment: @Tudor-RaduBarbu Try moving the route earlier in the file. Laravel uses the first matched route, and I find a Resource:: route will often block more specific routes below it.

Answer (score 0):

i came across this link : [Laravel Nova - Point Nova path to resource page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337077/laravel-nova-point-nova-path-to-resource-page)

Not sure it's a permanent solution but editing LoginController.php will do.

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    return Nova::path().'/resources/***<resource_name>***;
}
```

**change  to your own resource name